# a "import '***.css';"statement found in a ESM file in monaco-editor npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules, monaco-editor

I don't know why developers of monaco-editor add these statements, they caused errors on my browser like

```
Failed to load module script: 
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

[image: css import list]

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-known [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/886) in the monaco-editor.

This guy says it all in his [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/886#issuecomment-640096468). You can't get monaco-editor to work without your own bundler (like webpack) to handle the CSS imports.

For examples, you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/samples/package.json).